# What is Chassidus?

Tags: chasidut-hasidism, avodath-hashem

I have heard people say that Chassidus is all different kinds of things. Probably the most often said thing I have heard is that it emphasizes avodas Hashem be'simcha. Now while that might be true, it's a Torah principle and not something made up by a (relatively) modern movement.

I have not learnt much Chassidus and so I'm not familiar myself with what the revolution is/was, so I'm wondering what it was that was so new and how Chassidus defines itself?

Comment: Are you asking about the chassidus of Satmar, Ger, Belz et al, or about the older "חסידים" that are mentioned in mishnayos? ....for the former, I can't help you; for the latter, read מסילת ישרים (esp his הקדמה)

Comment: I'm talking about the movement that began or was based on the Ba'al ShemTov.

Comment: How does the fact that something is a Torah principle preclude a modern movement being defined by a special emphasis on that principle?

Comment: http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Judaism/hasidim_&_mitnagdim.html

Answer (score 4):

[The Lubavitche Rebbe](http://www.chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/inyono/1) said that there are four explanations on "What is Chassidus":

1. The [Jewish] world was in a faint, and the Baal Shem Tov woke them up.
2. A Chossid does more than the law requires
3. Through Chassidus, a person can change his natural traits to G-dly traits.
4. Chassidus innovated that even a simple unrefined person can understand G-dliness

The Rebbe said that these are the "result" of a deeper explanation of Chassidus - that Chassidus is a new light from "Pnimiyus Atik".

Later on, the Rebbe said that it's a "foretaste" of the Torah of Moshiach, which is a revelation of Hashem's essence.

Comment: Are these historical facts about what the Baal Shem instituted, or conjecture of the theoretical chassid? Is number two a reality of the way first and second generation chassidim lived their lives? There were claims made against them that a full set of Shaas couldn't be found amongst an entire town.

Comment: @user6591, those claims were lies.

Comment: @Yishai That's what the groups descended from those chassidim say. People who trace their heritage to the Gra and Reb Chaim Voloshin would not agree.

Comment: I am not trying to pour salt on old wounds. B.H. both chassidim and regular Jews seem to be leading a life of Torah and yiraas shomayim so no-one need take offence at old accusations aimed at previous generations. In fact if you brought the Gra and the Besht to choose from a modem day society to be their followers i wonder who each would choose. That being said, claims were made, in print, had there been a real defence? Would a new group garner such animosity if they were obviously religious super men?

Comment: @user6591, since then a lot more information is available. There is no teaching anywhere in Chassidus to not learn Torah, or to not learn Shas. But I think you are misunderstanding the point of #2. The point is that the teaching inspire and are intended to inspire going Lifnim MiShuras HaDin, not that anyone who ever learnt it achieved that. Regarding claims made in print. Printing rumors is cheap, refuting them is expensive (go find the alledged town, investigate and print the truth). And anyway, access to print anything was highly political in those days.

Comment: @user6591, BTW, I have been reading up recently on the opposition to the Rambam. The parallels are striking. Not sure what to make of that ...

Comment: @Yishai at least two of the Rambam's endevures were extremely revolutionary and at least seemingly contradicted talmudic practice, that is his codification of laws and more so his involvement in philosophy. What revolutionary counter talmudic stand did chassidim take?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18257/discussion-between-yishai-and-user6591).

Comment: @Yishai to put it poetically, politically, and politely, Shmuel bidoro k'Yiphtach bidoro.' Yiphtach' saved a tremendous amount of klal yisroel for generations to come. Why do we have to turn around and pretend he was 'Shmuel'?

Comment: @user6591 But just because Yirmiyahu had opposition (from a formerly good prophet, no less), doesn't make him a Yiftach.

Comment: @Shmuel I am not basing that qualification on the opposition. I am basing it on what i think he was and whom he seemed to attract. Again, this is not an insult but people can't deal with it. Every gadol biography nowadays is the same exact thing with the names changed because we can't accept that one was a Baal chessed and one was a masmid, instead they are both both!

Comment: @Shmuel also deciding who and what he was and did is very hard because every description found its called a malicious fraud by the people who call themselves his followers and no real description is given by them. Only a hisnagdus to the misnagdim.

Comment: @Yishai - It is a myth that the Rambam was so opposed. The fact is that he was accepted by the majority of the world in his day, even his *Moreh* and *Sefer HaMada`*. This is attested to by various sources, including the Beth Yosef. His opposition was centered mainly in France on the part of a relatively small number of *hakhamim*, many of whom later did *teshuvah*. Read the information available - the mass "rejection" of the Rambam is simply not true. Kol tuv.

Comment: @Maimonist, I'm sure I won't convince you, but the opposition was most *extreme* in France, but opposition was far and wide. He was also accepted by many. One of the main motivators of that was his willingness to stand up for those who were pushed aside by others. As I said, the parallels are striking.

Comment: @Yishai - No, you won't convince me. I have read too much about this to go along with that. You would have to prove that the opposition went beyond a small group in France that had influence in some parts of Spain. Remember the sages of Lunel, France? They were devoted to the MT. It is an urban legend used to dismiss the Rambam as an iconoclast. While he was in certain ways, they were overwhelmingly welcomed by the religious Jewish world as a continuation of the rationalism of Hai and Sherira z"l (the mystical texts attributed to Hai are forgeries). Read about it.

Comment: @Maimonist, since you have already made up your mind, I'm not sure why you are starting this conversation.

Comment: @Yishai - I was only making a comment to correct a commonly-held misperception. I made up my mind based on historical facts and the attending documents from that time and following. It is you, rather, that has made up your mind that there is some sort of "parallel" between the halakhic and philosophical works of Maimonides and the heretical movement introduced by the Besht that was ultimately put into *hherem* by the Jewish leaders of the time. Regardless of how one thinks of either figure, to make their lives parallel is a contrived reach for sure. (We have been at this impasse before). KT.

Comment: @Yishai - My honest thought is that you would read about it further. Guess not and that is your business. Kol tuv.

Comment: @Maimonist, I can't imagine what you were expecting me to read when you didn't quote anything.

Comment: Start with the letters of the Rambam and the various communities with which he interacted during his lifetime. Then try reading *Milhhamoth HaShem* by Rabbenu Avraham ben HaRambam and the letters that led up to it. The English version by Fred Rosner has a some great information on this in an appendix. The upset was on the part of a small group in France who were essentially "christian" in their *hashqafah* and their simplistic reading of Biblical texts. The research of Jose Faur is also of great importance. Enjoy. Kol tuv.

Comment: @user6591 there were many lies made up or greatly exaggerated. To take your example at the time there were many shuls on every single corner in Jewish towns. Many of these little shuls were segregated by people's profession and I certainly would not assume that every shul had a large collection of books available. Books were not always as accessible to the Jewish community as they are now. In fact now they are more accessible than ever before in Jewish history.

Comment: A example of a lie that is both funny and shows the great extents to which people went to try to discredit chassidim was about the Alter Rebbe. The misnagdim at the time spread a rumor that on tisha b'av he was seen eating meat and drinking wine with a girl on his lap. the truth was it was a year in which tisha b'av was on a shabbos and so the fast was pushed off and this girl was his granddaughter.

Comment: @Dude What's the source of that rumor?

Comment: @Dude That sounds more like a story Chasidim made up to make the Misnagdim look like liars in their efforts to discredit Chasidim. More likely is that the Chasidim were actually doing some weird things and thanks to the Misnagdim's critiquing them they've become more normal. Today's Chasidim ought to be thankful to the Misnagdim and stop spreading lies about their efforts to save traditional Judaism from some early weirdos.

Comment: @DoubleAA no that is part of the lies that misnagdem created when they apposed the baal shem tov and the early leaders of the movement. they even went as far to report to the government false acts of treason and people were murdered as a result. It was a terrible time for Jews. Thankfully today people have realized this sort of fighting against chassidus is wrong. Today Jews realize that there would be no simcha in Judaism if it weren't for chassidus and there would be no frumkeit in America if it wasn't for the Rebbe Rayatz. You are clearly very misinformed about history.

Comment: @Dude You can claim that one side is all lies if you want, but without proof it's not a meaningful claim to anyone. I just said what your story sounds like. It sounds completely made up. Anyone would agree with that. Try bringing sources and facts to discussions if you want them to be meaningful. Basing your worldview on made up fantastical stories about how you were the underdog and the other side hurt you is rather shallow. People stopped fighting Chasidus because they stopped being so weird.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be asking two things:

1. "what it was that was so new" – past tense: when chassidus was a new thing
2. "how Chassidus defines itself" – present tense: chassidus today

So, in very short form:

1. Increasing emotional attachment to Judaism by incorporating aspects of kabbalah into daily life (esp. prayers and rituals) under the closer supervision of a very learned scholar, a rebbe.
2. Adhering to the guidance, customs, and enactments of the current (or last) rebbe.

Comment: @Ypnypn The Gra was also into Kabbalah, yet wasn't a Chossid. Sefardim bring Kabbalah into Halacha more than Chassidim, yet aren't generally called "Chassidim"

Comment: the name chassidim and misnagdem were both created by the people who apposed the approach of the the baal shem tov. chassidim being meant to be mocking them for having false piety. The baal shem tov called his students reim ahuvim

Comment: @Dude. True, but I don't think the OP meant that.

Answer (score 2):

The most susinct summation of what the Ba'al Shem Tov innovated I have seen is from the Previous Lubavitcher Rebbe in [Kuntres Toras HaChassidus](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15658&st=&pgnum=5&hilite=):

> מורנו הבעש"ט נ"ע פתח צנור היכולת בעבודת השי"ת, בהוראה והדרכה אשר כל אחד ואחד מישראל יכול לעבוד את הוי' באהבה וביראה. גם אנשים פשוטים הנה על ידי תמימות עבודתם באמירת תהלים - אף גם כשאינם יודעים פירוש המלות - ואהבת ישראל מתקרבים המה בהתקרבות פנימי אל ה', להיות כי העיקר הוא המעשה והעבודה בתם לב
>
> Out teacher the Ba'al Shem Tov opened a way in the ability to search Hashem in showing and instructing that each and every Jew is able to serve Hashem with love and fear. Including simple people through their sincerity in their service of reciting Tehilim - even if they don't know what the words mean - and love of their fellow Jew they become close with an inner closeness to Hashem, because the main thing is the action and service with a sincere heart.