# What is Chassidut meantioned by the Misilat Yeshorim?

Tags: words, ramchal

The Misilat Yeshorim writes:

There are many who deal with Halachic  discussions,  others  with  Midrash  and  others  with  legal  decisions. There are few, however, who devote thought to true Chassidut.

What does Chassidut mean? Why is it so important? and Why isn't it popular?

Comment: not related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47827/759

Comment: I don't have a _MY_ at hand, but seem to recall that he devotes an entire chapter to explaining "_chasidus_". Am I mistaken? If not, there's your answer, I guess, to "What does Chassidut mean?".

Comment: @msh210 So what does he mean in the introduction?

Answer (score 1):

The Messilat Yesharim gives a definition in chapter [18](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01181.html?dyn#HtmpReportNum0018_L2), "Definition of Midat Chasidut (CONCERNING THE TRAIT OF SAINTLINESS)" here is an extract:

> הנה שורש החסידות הוא מה שאמרו זכרונם לברכה (ברכות יז, א) אשרי אדם שעמלו בתורה ועושה נחת רוח ליוצרו. והענין הוא כי הנה המצות המוטלות על כל ישראל כבר ידועות הן וחובתן ידועה עד היכן היא מגעת, אמנם מי שאוהב את הבורא יתברך שמו אהבה אמתית לא ישתדל ויכוין לפטור עצמו במה שכבר מפורסם מן החובה אשר על כל ישראל בכלל, אלא יקרה לו כמו שיקרה אל בן אוהב אביו שאילו יגלה אביו את דעתו גילוי מעט שהוא חפץ בדבר מן הדברים, כבר ירבה הבן בדבר ההוא ובמעשה ההוא כל מה שיוכל. ואף על פי שלא אמרו אביו אלא פעם אחת ובחצי דיבור, הנה די לאותו הבן להבין היכן דעתו של אביו נוטה לעשות לו, גם את אשר לא אמר לו בפירוש, כיון שיוכל לדון בעצמו שיהיה הדבר ההוא נחת רוח לפניו ולא ימתין שיצוהו יותר בפירוש או שיאמר לו פעם אחרת. ‏
>
> The underlying idea is this: It is
> known which mitzvoth are binding on all of Israel and to what extent one is bound by them.
> However, one who truly loves the Creator may His Name be blessed, will not endeavor and
> intend to fulfill his obligations by means of the duty which is acknowledged by all of Israel in
> general, but will react in very much the same manner as a son who loves his father, who, even if
> his father gives only a slight indication of desiring something, undertakes to fulfill this desire as
> completely as he can.

Here is a [link](http://www.israel613.com/books/MESILAT_YESHARIM.pdf) for an English online translation (I pasted my quotes from it).

---

You ask Why is it so important and why isn't it popular. I assume that is exactly what you are referring to about the importance. This statement:

> אך מעטים יהיו מן המין הזה אשר יקבעו עיון ולמוד על עניני שלמות העבודה, על האהבה, על היראה, על הדבקות, ועל כל שאר חלקי החסידות. ולא מפני שאין דברים אלה עקרים אצלם, כי אם תשאל להם, כל אחד יאמר שזהו העיקר הגדול. ושלא ידומה חכם, שיהיה חכם באמת, שלא יתבררו אצלו כל הדברים האלה.  אך מה שלא ירבו לעיין עליו הוא מפני רוב פרסום הדברים ופשיטותם אצלם שלא יראה להם צורך להוציא בעיונם זמן רב.‏
> There are few, owever... etc (see in the PDF [here](http://www.israel613.com/books/MESILAT_YESHARIM.pdf) for english translation)

The author says that everybody thinks that perfectionment of Avoda is very important. He explains that it is not popular because people think that a little thinking is needed to understand the ways of Avoda. But their are wrong.

Comment: So why does he call in the introduction his whole Sefer a path of chassidut?

Comment: @ MosheRabbi because everybody knows a little, Mitchassed im kono, lifnim mishurat hadin etc. but after this he begins to explain exactly.

Comment: I dont understand so why does he call his all Sefer like that?

Comment: @MosheRabbi 1) at the end of chapter19 "למען תזכה לשבת את פניו בכלל הישרים והחסידים". 2) in the end of the book   "אמר המחבר הפעם אודה את ה' אשירה ואזמרה, אשר עד הנה עזרוני רחמיו להוציא לאור ספרי זה מסלת ישרים אשר להתלמד בו חברתיו, ולהועיל לשכמותי לרבים נתתיו. אולי אזכה שיזכו אחרים על ידי, וייטב להם בעבורי, ואעשה נחת רוח ליוצרי. ותהי זאת נחמתי בארץ תלאובות, ואקרא שמה רחובות. כן יאמר ה' לתת חלקי בתורתו, ללמוד וללמד לשמור ולעשות. וחפצו בידי יצליח אמן כן יהי רצון. "
1n chapter 3 messila: mashal of labyrinth

Comment: Youre not explaining why the whole Sefer is called like that in the Hakdama.

Comment: I say again. the name of the sefer is  explained in the last lines of the book. the choice of Mesila is explained in the end of the chapter 3, messila yeshara is one of the ways of the labyrinth that keep you at the end.

Comment: I understand but why is it called Chassius.

Comment: @MosheRabbi see my answer for why its called that in the hakdama

Comment: I don't know why someone down voted my answer. The answer seems to solve the OP, the second question of MoshRabbi is a next question. @ray what you think?

Comment: @MosheRabbi the sefer is not called mesilat chasidim

Comment: @kouty i downvoted thinking you missed the intent of the question. the op's question should be made clearer. though seems too obvious to be asking just for the trait of piety mentioned in ch.18. i could retract downvote but wont let me till you edit the question.

Comment: @ray I admit that the first question wase the only one that I answered, The next 2 questions are about the importance and the unpopularity. It seems to be obviously treated in the next statements of the introduction.  The book of RY Sarna is wonderful, very interesting. It is important to know that in this book the version of the MY is not complete. The book is Yunim, not really a perush

Answer (score 0):

it is confusing what he means in the introduction regarding piety. He starts and ends his book talking about piety, although "piety" is merely one of the traits listed in the ladder of ascent.

Here is an excerpt of a commentary from Rabbi Yechezkel Sarna on the Mesilas Yesharim which explains what it is doing in the introduction of the book (I am answering this based on my understanding of your [comments](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70793/what-is-chassidut-meantioned-by-the-misilat-yeshorim/70839#comment204675_70802)):

> Rabeinu called his book "the Path of the Just", not "the Path of the
>   Pious" despite that he opens his book with the "foundation of piety"
>   (in ch.1) and in the final section of the book says: "I did not finish
>   in this book all the principles of piety", and then goes on to
>   elaborate on "piety" until the end of the book. Likewise, in the
>   introduction, he speaks at length on piety, and so too in many
>   chapters of the book besides the chapters specifically designated to
>   the trait of piety.
>
> It seems because piety is not the final end asked of man. It is merely
>   a level among the levels counted in the Beraitha of Rabbi Pinchas ben
>   Yair which Rabeinu in his book expounds one by one. The final end
>   asked of man is that he be "Yashar" Just/Upright as G-d made him. As
>   written "G-d has made man upright [but they have sought out many
>   schemes]..." (Eccl. 7:29).
>
> Our sages asked (Avodah Zara 25a): "why is [Genesis] called the 'Book
>   of the Just'? Because it is the book of the Just, namely the holy
>   forefathers (Abraham, Isaac, Jacob) which are called Just." Hence,
>   this is what is asked of man. As written in Tana d'Bei Eliyahu, "a man
>   is obligated to say 'when will my deeds reach those of my forefathers,
>   Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob'". And that which Rabeinu speaks about the
>   trait of piety, opening and sealing his book with it, this is because
>   **he wages a massive war campaign against the "Mitchasdim" (false pious)**
>   in this book which are "most people" who consider many customs and many ways as
>   "piety" but they are only fallacious piety... and there is no trait of
>   all the traits counted by Rabbi Pinchas ben Yair of whom there is more
>   misunderstanding than piety. But what G-d asks of us is to that we be
>   Yesharim (upright/just). For this includes all the traits. For a
>   person who lacks even one of them is already not considered Yashar. Rather
>   he is among those who "sought out many schemes".

from Mesilas Yesharim with english commentaries [here](http://dafyomireview.com/mesilat.php?d=2&e=2).

original hebrew of Rabbi Sarna is at www.hebrewbooks.org/41769 in the hakdama